# Map selected fields from multiple POJOs to create one POJO

Tags: java, mapping

I have a couple of objects from which selected members should be combined to create an output object. All these are POJOs. I am seeing that all object mappers work on a single POJO to another POJO level. Is there any mapper that supports what I am looking for? Of course, I understand that there is some mapping stuff that I need to specify.

Edit:
I know how to get this done by writings own Java class. I am just looking for a way to do it with one of the mapping libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't limited in what you require to be passed to your mapper.  You can define it to accept several items and build the object based on the multiple inputs.  Here is an example:

```
public class ClassOne {
    private final String someProperty;

    public ClassOne(String someProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }

    public String getSomeProperty() {
        return someProperty;
    }
}

public class ClassTwo {
    private final String someOtherProperty;

    public ClassTwo(String someOtherProperty) {
        this.someOtherProperty = someOtherProperty;
    }

    public String getSomeOtherProperty() {
        return someOtherProperty;
    }
}

public class CombinedClass {

    public static CombinedClass mapper(ClassOne one, ClassTwo two){
        return new CombinedClass(one.getSomeProperty(), two.getSomeOtherProperty());
    }

    private final String someProperty;
    private final String someOtherProperty;

    private CombinedClass(String someProperty, String someOtherProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
        this.someOtherProperty = someOtherProperty;
    }

    public String getSomeProperty() {
        return someProperty;
    }

    public String getSomeOtherProperty() {
        return someOtherProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I know how to get this done by writing the required code. I am just interested in finding out if any of the mapping libraries can do this. Sorry about my question not being clear. I will edit it to add the information.